# How to recursively all sub directories with only one file inside

Tags: shell

How can I recursively delete from a directory all its sub directories with only one file inside, and the file's name contains key word "DEL" and the file was created before 2017?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely not possible, but you can come at least close to it:

The idea is to use `find` to travel through all the directories. Have a look at the `-type` flag, so that `find` picks up directories only.

With the `-exec` option of `find`, you pass the name of a program which checks, whether this is a directory to be deleted. I'm not sure whether it is safe to delete it right now (I think it is), or whether it would upset `find` (in which case you would just print the path of the directory to stdout, so that it can be deleted by the script which is invoking `find`), so this is something you have to try out.

Thr tricky part is to find whether this is a directory to be deleted. Finding the number of files in a directory can be done in different ways, and it depends on which programming language you use for this "checking program".

Matching the filename is trivial.

What won't work is finding out the creation date in case you are on Linux or Unix, because it is not stored anywhere. The closest you can get is the *inode change time*. If you are on Windows, you can find out the creation date.